# Is any configuration required to consume Web Api service (which developed for Black berry) for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-web-api

We developed a Web API for Blackberry. Now I have a requirement that, these services should work the same for Android and IOS also.

Is any config changes required for Web API to work the same for Android and IOS?

Comment: you are asking you to do configuaration at server level or client side??

Comment: @malli thanks for the reply. I am asking about server side

Comment: Definately we need to do respective configuarations at server level.But i am not a server side developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. As long as the WebService API is HTTP based e.g (REST/SOAP), then you can simply use the same WebService for both iOS & Android.

However, you might need to do some customizations for each client. This may occur for different scenarios.

E.g: Suppose you're hosting an image on the server. Then you might need to have several versions of the image for iOS & Androids because of the screen densities.

Another example is if you need to register for push notifications in your WebServer. Then you might need to make slight adjustments.

So in general, you don't really need to change in Big. But, you might need to do some minor customizations.